# Linq XDocument return a list of elements based on 2 attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Is it possible to return a list of elements based on 2 matching attribute values. I've tried the following with no success.

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("Root")
.Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Value1")
.Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Value2")
.Select(x => (string)x.Element("ElementName");
```

Here's sample xml structure

```
    <Region Name="Leeds">
        <Group>
            <Data1>Some data 1</Data1>
            <Data2>Some data 2</Data2>
        </Group>
<Group>
            <Data1>Some data 1</Data1>
            <Data2>Some data 2</Data2>
        </Group>

    </Region>
    <Region Name="Armley">
        <Group>
            <Data1>Some data 3</Data1>
            <Data2>Some data 4</Data2>
        </Group>
    </Region>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont you just want an `OR`?

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `||` within the same `Where` clause as @Adil suggested, or use `Contains`:

```
var names = new [] { "Value1", "Value2" };

var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("Root")
                     .Where(x => names.Contains((string)x.Attribute("Name")))
                     .Select(x => (string)x.Element("ElementName");
```

I also changed `XAttribute.Value` to `(string)XAttribute` to make it more safe.

Comment: Thats curious, what makes the casting to a string more safe that getting the value?

Comment: It will not throw `NullReferenceException` when attribute with given name does not exist on that element.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use or `||` to get records where attribute `name` have either `value1` or `value2`. The statement you have will filter out records which have value1 for attribute name and then it will apply filter that attribute name should have value2 which is not possible unless value1 is equal to value2.

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("Root")
.Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Value1" || x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Value2")
.Select(x => (string)x.Element("ElementName");
```